# laravel 5.1 dynamic google map based on users location

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel-5.1

Would like to know how would I insert and google map in a user profile, that will show the user location based on the address in the mysql db. saw some tutorials but they are old and the new map variable is different, how to make it work?

Comment: you mean you want to save users location or show them ?

Answer (score 1):

replace pos object with your position values; here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/4mtyu/)

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
});

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

var pos = {
    lat: 40,
    lng: 74
};

infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
map.setCenter(pos);
```